# filter a df by all the values with dates before today's date

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I'd like to filter a `df` by date. But I would like all the values with any date before today's date (python).

For example from the table below, I'd like the rows that have a date before today's date  (i.e. row 1 to row 3).

| ID | date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-03-25 06:00:00 |
| 2 | 2022-04-25 06:00:00 |
| 3 | 2022-05-25 06:00:00 |
| 4 | 2022-08-25 06:00:00 |

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this?

```
from datetime import datetime

df[df['date'] < datetime.now()]
```

Output:

```
  ID                date
0  1 2022-03-25 06:00:00
1  2 2022-04-25 06:00:00
2  3 2022-05-25 06:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
#convert column to datetime object
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], infer_datetime_format=True, errors='coerce')

#filter column
df.loc[df['date'] < datetime.now()]
```